# Laravel get model without appends attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm working with Laravel 5.3 and in a Model `Post`, I have an appends attributes :

```
/*
* toJson
*/
protected $appends = ['count'];
```

And the magic method :

```
public function getCountAttribute()
    {
        return Offer::where('id', '=', $this->id)->count();
    }
```

So, when I get a `Post` model with eloquent like `Post::get()`, and get the return with json for example, I ALWAYS have this attribute `count` in my object.

How can I specify if I want or not this or another appends atribute ?

Comment: `Post::get()` isn't a valid method, do you mean `all`?

Comment: Yeah, was just for the example

Answer (score 6):

I checked how Eloquent models get serialized and unfortunately list of fields to be appended is not shared between all instances of given Model and the only way I see to achieve what you need is to iterate through the result set and explicitly enable append for selected attributes:

```
$posts = Post::all();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
  // if you want to add new fields to the fields that are already appended
  $post->append('count');

  // OR if you want to overwrite the default list of appended fields
  $post->setAppends(['count']);
}
```

Comment: Not very a good idea to iterate each time I get datas, it's better to keep the useless variable instead

Comment: That's true, as long as calculating the value is cheap. If it involves some complex logic that could have performance overhead, you might want to append it only when necessary. Anyway, that's the only way to do conditional append.

Comment: Hum, yep, not a good point for Laravel ^^ I'm working on an API and I don't like to keep useless datas in my different webservices

Answer (score 1):

You could get the model's attributes with `$post->getAttributes()` which returns an array of attributes before any appends